# Operator Precedence in Notation Package

Tags: custom-notation, precedence

I am trying to use the Notation package to define custom notation for chemical reactions. The natural thing to do is to use a

```
\[LongRightArrow]
```

for the operator. In particular, I would like to have the reactants grouped before the arrow, the products grouped after the arrow, and a rate constant over the arrow using Ctrl-7. But when I try to implement this with the Notations Package, I run into several problems. First, trying it as a binary operator without the rate constant over the arrow, the precedence of the arrow is too high, so it shifts products around to the reactants side. I have tried copying in example code from the [Complex Patters and Advanced Features](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html#4576917) source (specifically the Changing Precedences and the TagBox Option SyntaxForm section -- copying the code directly and attempting to modify with the LongArrow fails), setting the SyntaxForm option within a TagBox to something with a very low precedence, like "," or "==", but this doesn't change the output at all.

Example code:

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"a_", "\[LongRightArrow]", "b_"}]] 
\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"Reaction", "[", RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_"}], "]"}]]]
```

When used with the following example reaction:

```
2 C60s\[LongRightArrow]C60s + C60
```

Produces:

```
C60 + 2 C60s\[LongRightArrow]C60s
```

Changing the notation with a TagBox like so:

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"a_", 
TagBox["\[LongRightArrow]", Identity, SyntaxForm -> ","], "b_"}]]
\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"LongRightArrow", "[", 
RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_"}], "]"}]]]
```

Has no effect on my output from the example above. I have also tried using the Full Notation Palette with the Wrapper Boxes to no avail following advice in a StackExchange thread.

And this doesn't begin to address the issue of trying to get a third operand over the arrow.

Any help appreciated!

Edited to add: To get this to work seamlessly, we need the Notation line to include an extra " " between the "a_" and the TagBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an input alias for the [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox) version of the long right arrow:

```
AddInputAlias["rxn" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[TagBox["\[LongRightArrow]", Identity, SyntaxForm->","]]]
```

Then, you need to use the "rxn" alias to enter the long right arrow, and things should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't see a way to do this through the Palettes, which is a shame, but I am thrilled to have a way that works.